# Breaking change: extract now only takes a single argument

Tags: angular, webpack

I am getting following error while running build

```
ERROR in ./~/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.loader.js!./~/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js
Module build failed: Error: Breaking change: extract now only takes a single argument. Either an options object *or* the loader(s).
Example: if your old code looked like this:
    ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
```

You would change it to:

```
 ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader' })
```

The available options are:

```
loader: string | object | loader[]
fallbackLoader: string | object | loader[]
publicPath: string
```

following is my package.json:

```
    {
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-popover": "0.0.13",
    "primeng": "^1.1.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "argv": "0.0.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.2.2",
    "bootstrap-loader": "~1.2.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "browser-sync": "^2.9.11",
    "browser-sync-spa": "^1.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "css-to-string-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "del": "^2.0.2",
    "eslint": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-config-xo-space": "^0.12.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "github:steinpilz/extract-text-webpack-plugin#type-error-investigations",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "gulp": "gulpjs/gulp#4ed9a4a3275559c73a396eff7e1fde3824951ebb",
    "gulp-filter": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-hub": "frankwallis/gulp-hub#d461b9c700df9010d0a8694e4af1fb96d9f38bf4",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.9.0",
    "isparta-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^0.13.14",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.5.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.4.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-source-map-support": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-story-reporter": "^0.3.1",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16-10",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.12",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.3",
    "sass-resources-loader": "~1.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "ts-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.2.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~2.1.4",
    "typings": "^1.4.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.22",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "webpack-fail-plugin": "^1.0.5",
    "yargs": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp",
    "serve": "gulp serve",
    "serve:dist": "gulp serve:dist",
    "test": "gulp test",
    "test:auto": "gulp test:auto",
    "postinstall": "typings prune && typings install"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "jasmine": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "xo-space/esnext"
    ]
  }
}
```

Following is my webpack-dist.conf

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const conf = require('./gulp.conf');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const NoErrorsPlugin = require('webpack-fail-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.json$/,
                loaders: [
                    'json'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallbackLoader: 'style',
                    loader: 'css-loader'
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallbackLoader: 'style',
                    loader: ['css', 'resolve-url', 'sass', 'sass-resources']
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'url',
                query: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    minetype: 'application/font-woff'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|jpg|png)$/,
                loader: 'url'
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: [
                    'ts'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /index\.html$/,
                loader: [
                    'html'
                ]
            }
        ],
        noParse: [ /zone\.js\/dist\/.+/, /angular2\/bundles\/.+/ ]
    },
    sassResources: conf.path.src('assets/styles/sass-resources.scss'),
    plugins: [
        //https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/993 fixes typescript warning
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            __dirname
        ),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        NoErrorsPlugin,
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: `${conf.path.src('index.html')}`,
            inject: true,
            appD: conf.getAppDID()
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
                'root': JSON.stringify(conf.paths.root)
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {unused: true, dead_code: true} // eslint-disable-line camelcase
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: 'index-[contenthash].css', allChunks: true}),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({names: ['vendor', 'polyfills']})
    ],
    postcss: () => [autoprefixer],
    output: {
        path: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.paths.dist),
        filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
            '',
            '.webpack.js',
            '.web.js',
            '.js',
            '.ts'
        ]
    },
    debug: false,
    bail: true,
    entry: {
        polyfills: `./${conf.path.src('polyfills')}`,
        vendor: `./${conf.path.src('vendor')}`,
        app: `./${conf.path.src('index')}`
    },
    ts: {
        configFileName: 'tsconfig.json'
    },
    tslint: {
        configuration: require('../tslint.json'),
        formattersDirectory: '../node_modules/tslint-loader/formatters/',
        failOnHint: true
    }
};
```

Someone guide me, what am I doing wrong

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkrAs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your `bootstrap-loader` (v1) requires `"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "<2.0.0"` as a [peer dependency](https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader/blob/v1/package.json#L39) and they invoke it like version 1. But you have a version over `2.0.0`. You should upgrade `boostrap-loader` to their version 2 as well:

```
npm install --save-dev bootstrap-loader@latest
```

While you're at it, you should probably also upgrade `extract-text-webpack-plugin` because that fork you're using is very far behind. And the official `extract-text-webpack-plugin` package is no longer in beta, nor is `webpack`.

Comment: after updating to version 2 of bootstrap loader, I am getting another error "Can't resolve sass-loader-resources". Can you suggest, what is wrong here

Comment: I don't know. Did you accidentally use `sass-loader-resources` instead of `sass-resources-loader` in your webpack config?

Comment: Exactly, so if you accidentally wrote `sass-loader-resources` somewhere in your webpack config, it won't work, because the package is called `sass-resources-loader`.

Comment: no it wasn't updated accidentally, there is no change in my package.json

Comment: I am ***not*** talking about the package.json, you should ***not*** write `sass-loader-resources` but you probably did, otherwise that error makes no sense. So search for it! It's probably somewhere in your ***webpack*** config.

Comment: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sass-loader-resources' in 'D:\mdp-internaltools-app\node_modules\bootstrap-loader'. This is the error I am getting, it is the error in bootstrap loader itself

Comment: @Micheal Jungo , I have added an image above with the console output, could you please help